Share command output between nodes
I would like to share the output of a command from one node to the other on running salt "*" state.apply.
My current solution involves mine.send and mine.get:
$ cat top.sls
base:
  'master*':
    - states.master*

  'worker*':
    - states.worker*

$ cat states/master.sls
save:
  module.run:
    - mine.send:
      - foo
      - mine_function: cmd.shell
      - name: whoami

$ cat states/worker.sls
load:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/a.sh
    - contents: {{ salt['mine.get']("*", "foo").values() | first }}

On first run, I get the following error for the "worker" node:
worker-0:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:states.worker' failed: Jinja variable No first item, sequence was empty.; line 7

---
[...]
load:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/a.sh
    - contents: {{ salt['mine.get']("*", "foo").values() | first }}
---

On second run it works as expected.
I am assuming that the problem is that the mine.get does not wait for the mine.send but it tries to fetch the variable on creating the template.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Because you are looking at a relationship between events happening on different minions I believe you are looking for the orchestrate runner that

is executed on the master, giving it a master-level view and control
over requisites, such as state ordering and conditionals. This allows
for inter minion requisites, like ordering the application of states
on different minions that must not happen simultaneously, or for
halting the state run on all minions if a minion fails one of its
states.

